# using Github actions with codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services

[image]I am using GitHub Actions with CodeBuild but whenever I run the workflow I am getting error message:
*****STARTING CODEBUILD*****

[24]([https://github.com/jude![Error|563x470](upload://3wIYvCwrkHB6AnfkeJqtWd1cSWI.png)](https://github.com/jude!%5BError%7C563x470%5D(upload://3wIYvCwrkHB6AnfkeJqtWd1cSWI.png))
0143143/CodeBuild/runs/3692850080?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:24)Error: The security token included in the request is invalid

name: 'GitHub Actions For CodeBuild'
on:
pull_request:
branches:
- test
env:
tf_version: 'latest'
tg_version: 'latest'
jobs:
deploy:
name: 'Build and Deploy'
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
  - name: 'checkout'
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: configure AWS credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: us-east-1
      role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
      role-duration-seconds: 3600

  - name: Run CodeBuild
    uses: aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build@v1
    with:
      project-name: CodeBuild
      buildspec-override: stage/dev-env/buildspec.yml
      env-vars-for-codebuild: |
        TF_INPUT,
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        AWS_REGION,
        ROLE_TO_ASSUME,
        ROLE_DURATION_SECONDS,
     
    env:
      TF_INPUT: false 
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: us-east-1
      ROLE_TO_ASSUME: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
      ROLE_DURATION_SECONDS: 3600[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the given role or keys are not valid to execute the action.

You set access key and secret key in both the 'configure AWS credentials' and 'Run CodeBuild' steps. Looking into the Repository for 'aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build@v1' it seems that it only needs to be configured in the first step. Not sure how many environments you are expecting to deploy to but if there is only one, then *env* is redundant.

https://github.com/aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build

Somethink like this I expect:

```
steps:
  - name: 'checkout'
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: configure AWS credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: us-east-1
      role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
      role-duration-seconds: 3600

  - name: Run CodeBuild
    uses: aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build@v1
    with:
      project-name: CodeBuild
      buildspec-override: stage/dev-env/buildspec.yml
```